# Can I redirect data from an HTTP GET request through a POST request without downloading the payload myself?

Tags: http, post, get

Currently, I can do this:

1. I send GET request to Server A
2. I receive payload from Server A
3. I send POST request to Server B
4. Server B receives payload from me

but is it possible to make the payload go straight from A to B? With me having to only "orchestrate" the move like this:

1. I tell Server A to send payload to Server B (somehow)
2. Server B receives payload from Server A

Note: I do not control either server

---

My use case: I want to restream a livestream to YouTube via HLS

[This guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/guides/hls-ingestion#obtaining_an_hls_ingestion_url_from_youtube_creator_studio) by YouTube says that I need to send my files via POST requests to
`https://a.upload.youtube.com/http_upload_hls?cid=$STREAM_KEY&copy=0&file=$FILE_PATH`

[Here](https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8) is a sample payload. It's a `playlist.m3u8` file that YouTube expects

I tried just putting that URL in `$FILE_PATH`, but it returned a `400 (Bad request)`

Comment: somehow it may look like a proxy but you are surely not telling the whole story so probably the real answer is no unless you have an endpoint on A that it's already having the logic to contact server B (even through parameters) so that its response will be redirected by A to you (in the context of the very first request you made to A)

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I added my example use case